# Domain transfer (.com to .ca) via DNS issue

Tags: server, dns, localhost, hosting, nameservers

The domain owner of tempotechcontrols.com updated DNS records for tempotechcontrols.com to redirect it to tempotechcontrols.ca however, it's not working for the past 2-3 days.

1. tempotechcontrols.com is hosted on the local server of the domain owner.
2. tempotechcontrols.ca is hosted on one.com hosting provider.

Any kind of help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should ask your domain owner. The redirect is on his side. Impossible for anyone here to second guess his settings.

Comment: There was some issue with the one.com guys and I moved the domain to hover.com and all seems working. Thanks for the quick reply!